# Calculate $P(1 \le X \le 2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with distribution function

$$f(X)= \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0, &  X < 0, \\
X/8, & 0 \le X < 1, \\
1/4 + X/8, & 1 \le X < 2, \\
3/4 + X/12, & 2 \le X < 3\end{array}\right.
$$

Calculate $P(1 \le X \le 2).$

Comment: Calculate $F(2)-F(1)$.

Comment: hello Jessica, people would probably be more willing to help you if you post what you have tried to do so far.

Comment: kk so I tried:

P(1)=F(1)-F(0)=1/4+x/8-x/8=1/4

P(2)=F(2)-F(1)=3/4+x/12-1/4-x/8=1/4-x/24

Then, 

P(1 ≤ X ≤ 2)=P(2)-P(1)=1/4-x/24-1/4=-x/24

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $P(a \leq X \leq b) = F(b) - lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F(a-\frac{1}{n})$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us analyze the cumulative distribution function at the interesting points $x=1$ and $x=2$. For reasons of tradition, we will call the cdf by the name $F(x)$.

As $x$ approaches $1$ **from the left**, $F(x)$ approaches $\frac{1}{8}$.

But note that from the definition given, we have $F(1)=\frac{1}{4}$. So $\Pr(X\le 1)=\frac{1}{4}$. There is a dramatic jump in probability when we hit $x=1$.

This means there must be a **point mass** of $\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{8}$ at $x=1$.

A similar analysis shows that there is a point mass of size $\frac{1}{4}$ at $x=2$.

The weight up to and including $x=2$ is $\frac{3}{4}$. The weight $\le 1$ is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Thus $\Pr(1\lt X\le 2)=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$.  But this is not quite what we want, we want $\Pr(1\le X\le 2)$. So we must add $\Pr(X=1)$ to $\Pr(1\lt X\le 2)$. The result is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{8}$.

**Remark:** I visualize the situation as follows. Our distribution is a hybrid between a discrete distribution and a continuous distribution.  From $x=0$ to $x=1$, we have wire of density $\frac{1}{8}$. **At** $x=1$, we have a point mass of $\frac{1}{8}$. From $1$ to $2$, we have wire of density $\frac{1}{8}$. At $2$ we have a point mass of $\frac{1}{4}$. From $2$ to $3$ we have wire of density $\frac{1}{12}$. There is nothing before $0$ or after $3$.